# Macro to copy formula down to next cell in column and then paste above cell as value

Tags: excel, vba

in principle this one should be quite simple, I am having numerous issues with it however. This forms part of a bigger macro that has been put together to insert a new row at the bottom of my table. The tables are in various tabs that I have not specified in the macro (tabs not referenced <>), but I need to in the example look for the first value in the column where it exists and copy it down.

[image]

The above screenshot shows data in the table. Where it EXISTS, I need to copy it down to the next blank row. The Picture shows B5 as the first available blank row, whilst cell B4 has a formula In this instance B4 would be copied to B5 and B4 would become a value not formula. This could then change with B5 being copied to B6 and then B5 becoming a value when the macro is next run. The Blue Tab acceptance loose freight has five tables so I need to reference worksheets and column ranges for the tabs I want to effect. In the picture the tab is called "Acceptance Loose Freight" with data that needs to copy down in columns B, F, J , N & R.

```
Sub INSERT_NEW_ROWS()
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If rs.name <> "3110" And rs.name <> "Data" And rs.name <> "Wholesale" And _
           rs.name <> "Retail" And rs.name <> "Pivot 1" And rs.name <> "Pivot 2" And _
           rs.name <> "Pivot3" And rs.name <> "Pivot 4" And rs.name <> "Pivot 5" And _
           rs.name <> "Pivot 6" And rs.name <> "Pivot 7" And rs.name <> "Pivot 8" And _
           rs.name <> "Pivot 9" And rs.name <> "Pivot 10" And rs.name <> "Pivot 11" Then
            ' LastRow in column A
            LastRowa = rs.Cells(rs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ' LastRow in column B
            LastRowb = rs.Cells(rs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            'Copy paste the last row, based on what's in column A in the next empty row   
            rs.Cells(LastRowa, 2).EntireRow.Copy
            rs.Cells(LastRowa + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

            'Change the formula of the last cell in column  B into a value
            rs.Cells(LastRowb, 2).Copy
            rs.Cells(LastRowb + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            rs.Cells(LastRowb, 2).Value = rs.Cells(LastRowb, 2).Value
        End If
    Next rs   
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please ask a question? We cannot see where your issue is if you don't tell us. Do you get any errors? If so which and where? • Also it is unclear what exactly needs to be copied to which destination. Please clarify by [edit]ing your original question.

Comment: PEH I was under the impression the above is a question, is it not?!?! I amended the question mate, let me know if that makes sense. It is very simple what I am trying to achieve, I've just hit a brick wall....

Comment: Questions usually end with question marks, you posted just a requirement (which is not directly a question that can be answered). The main issue is you didn't tell what is going wrong with your code. Why does your code not work? • If my answer below does not provide a solution please be more specific about **where exactly** your issue is or where exactly you have difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

1. Instead of multiple `If … And … And … And …` use an array to list excluded worksheets and test if the current worksheet name `IsInArray`.
2. Build a second loop to loop through all the desired columns that you name in an array `AffectedColumns`.

For example:

```
Option Explicit 'see https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html

Public Sub InsertNewRows()
    Dim ExcludedWorksheets As Variant
    ExcludedWorksheets = Array("3110", "Data", "Wholesale", "Retail", "Pivot 1", "Pivot 2", "Pivot3", "Pivot 4", "Pivot 5", "Pivot 6", "Pivot 7", "Pivot 8", "Pivot 9", "Pivot 10", "Pivot 11")

    Dim AffectedColumns As Variant
    AffectedColumns = Array("B", "F", "J", "N", "R")

    Dim iCol As Variant
    Dim LastRowInCol As Long

    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not IsInArray(rs.Name, ExcludedWorksheets) Then

            For Each iCol In AffectedColumns
                LastRowInCol = rs.Cells(rs.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
                rs.Cells(LastRowInCol, iCol).Copy
                rs.Cells(LastRowInCol + 1, iCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
                rs.Cells(LastRowInCol, iCol).Value = rs.Cells(LastRowInCol, iCol).Value
            Next iCol
        End If
    Next rs
End Sub


Public Function IsInArray(FindString As String, InArray As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(InArray, FindString)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: PEH Sorry about the question mark. The macro I have is already inserting a new row at the bottom of my data, I need to incorporate copying the formula down tot he next available cell, which unfortunately this isn't doing. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @user3515236 Well my code should exactly do that *"copying the formula down to the next available cell"* in columns B, F, J , N & R

Comment: PEH Sorry about the question mark. I have noticed this is working correctly on column f in my data row 1 is being copied to row 2 and then row pasted as values. so it is working just not in the columns I specified, which is bizarre as I believe the iCol +1 is looking for this?

Comment: I don't understand what are you referring to. There is no `iCol +1` in my code. All the columns where data should be copied to the next row are listed in `AffectedColumns = Array("B", "F", "J", "N", "R")` so it only works on these columns

Comment: I.e. I have a today formula in column f in some sheets, in some I do not only the tables. I works on the first row where data exists but is not working where there is several rows of data PEH. My email is acrasherkid@googlemail.com can I send you the workbook as it would be easier my friend?

Comment: @user3515236 Again. My code copies the last used cell in the columns `AffectedColumns` to the next empty cell below and replaces the copied cell by its value. If you have issues please go through your code step-by-step using F8 and check your variable values. • No sorry, we don't accept to receive Excel files, you need to describe everything properly in your question.